# Behat context in a trait

Tags: php, bdd, autoload, behat

The basic [Behat](http://behat.org/) use case recommends using `FeatureContext` class. Also, you can specify any other PHP classes in the `features/bootstrap` directory and they are loaded, but in the alphabetical order, no matter what the dependencies are.

Given there is a trait and a FeatureContext class:

```
features/bootstrap/FeatureContext.php
features/bootstrap/MyLovelyTrait.php
```

What is the best way to load it properly? Obviously, MyLovelyTrait is used within the FeatureContext:

```
class FeatureContext extends BehatContext {
    use MyLovelyTrait;
}
```

And that fails because `M > F`, in the alphabet.

I will be happy to use composer autoloading, but I don't want to `require_once` the `autoload.php` file in the top of `BehatContext.php` file. Is there a way to specify this in `behat.yml` configuration? Also, any other best practice answer regarding class-loading of Behat context files will be appreciated.

Comment: What about `features/bootstrap/Autoload.php` as `F > A`  and that autoloader then can load `MyLovelyTrait.php` if needed? Perhaps not very creative. Otherwise create a ticket and provide an updated test for https://github.com/Behat/Behat/blob/3.0/features/traits.feature as according to that feature, it should be supported already "out of the box" :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure this is answering your question but I am under the impression that you are trying to use multiple context files? If so you don't need the use statement instead within the FeatureContext.php construct method we use the line:

```
$this -> useContext('Subcontext', new Subcontext($parameters));
```

In this case the other context you want to use is called "Subcontext".

Comment: Hi, what's the benefit of using subcontexts, compared to traits? I see traits and composer autoloading are standard thing, subcotext is sort of "proprietary trait" specific to Behat.

Comment: I found this comment on behat documentation:
"PHP does not yet support horizontal reusability in its core feature set. While this functionality, called traits, is on the roadmap for PHP 5.4, Behat provides subcontexts as a stop-gap solution to achieve horizontal reusability until this functionality is available in a stable PHP release."
Which makes me think since traits are available we should not use subcontext, or should we?

Answer (score 1):

A good reason not to useContext('Subcontext') can be found in the [Changelog](https://github.com/Behat/Behat/blob/3.0/CHANGES.md) of the upcoming version 3 of Behat:

```
3.0.0beta1 / 2013-08-13
...
  * Subcontexts removed in favor of context pools
```

Comment: That's a valuable information, but not directly answering my question. What is the preferred way to create and load context pools in Behat 3.0? Are traits an option?

Answer (score 0):

I hacked around it by working with the grain of behat -- all my traits start with "A". Examples:

```
// FeatureContext.php is at features/bootstrap/FeatureContext.php
<?php

use Behat\Behat\Context\ClosuredContextInterface,
    Behat\Behat\Context\TranslatedContextInterface,
    Behat\Behat\Context\BehatContext,
    Behat\Behat\Exception\PendingException;
use Behat\Gherkin\Node\PyStringNode,
    Behat\Gherkin\Node\TableNode;

class FeatureContext extends BehatContext
{
    use AWebDriverContextTrait;
}
```

and

```
// AWebDriverContextTrait is at features/bootstrap/AWebDriverContextTrait.php
<?php

trait AWebDriverContextTrait {
    /**
     * @Given /^I am on "([^"]+)"/
     */
    public function iAmOnSite($url)
    {
        $this->driver = new \Behat\Mink\Driver\Selenium2Driver(
            'firefox',
            ''
        );
        $this->session = new \Behat\Mink\Session($this->driver);
        $this->session->start();
        $this->session->visit($url);
    }

    private $driver;
    private $session;
}
```